# run a function instead of redirect to other page (passportjs)

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I would like to know how to run a function when passport authenticating fails or succeed, for example

```
.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
      successRedirect: '/',
      failureRedirect: '/users/login', //I would like to run a function here instead of redirecting
      failureFlash: false
    })(req, res, next);
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass a function instead of the config object.

But make sure that you handle the request properly.

ie:

```
const login = function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err || !user) {
            console.log(err);

            return res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Something is not right',
                user: user
            });
        }
        req.login(user, {session: false}, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }

            return res.json({user});
        });
    })(req, res);
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your answer!